# JQuery not working with android browser

Tags: android, jquery

I have been using jquery for my web development for a while, and when i use android browser to view my work, i find out that all the jquery function like hide() show() doesn't seems to work.

Can anyone validate this for me, I wonder why jquery is not working for android browser, I am using 2.3.1 right now. Does anyone come across with this problem before?

Comment: I'm relatively uninformed on the topic, but doesn't Android support multiple browsers?  Is there really a single, unambiguous "Android browser"?

Comment: There is a browser that is indeed called "Android browser" that came with the Android OS until very recently (and may still ship with it). I believe that very recent versions of Android ship with Chrome as the default browser. Not sure if they removed Android browser or not. And, of course, the user can install Firefox (I think) or Dolphin (definitely) and probably many many others.

Comment: No the..... of course the user can install whatever browser they like in their smartphone. My point is of course get their default android browser working with my website

Comment: Have you checked in the setting for Enabling JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery works just fine in Android browser.  The problem isn't that jQuery doesn't work in Android. The problem is something else.

It's hard to say what that problem might be without any code, but you can try to get more hints as to what might be going wrong by looking in the JS error console (or whatever the equivalent is in Android or an Android emulator--basically, where JS errors are logged).

If you want to get super ambitious, you can try debugging it with Weinre or something like that.

Comment: I should maybe go ahead and download weinre debugger and check out what happen to my code i guess. Thanks buddy

Comment: I will accept your answer if there is no more people replying.'

Comment: It's not an correct answer, at least doesn't solve issue. I've seen that hide(), show() don't work properly on Android native browser (Android 4.2). There is no error on console. Browser doesn't render correctly.

Comment: i see firefox and chrome on android work fine with jquery by now, but the default 'Internet' browser on android doesnt. (my android 4.3)

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not post code, we do not know if you were loading your JS assets from the same domain or not. After putting jQuery on the same server instead of using a CDN it resolved my issue.  I also had other random JS errors and then I cleared all the data/cache for Chrome and that fully resolved it.

If the issue is something else, you can follow the instructions here to do remote debugging on any of the JavaScript errors:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Been doing my head in trying to get remote debugging for the device (bad usb cable it turns out) but referencing a local version of jquery fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Jquery current browser support on desktop and mobile: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

So seems the problem is not with jquery support for native android emulation, since Stock browser on Android 4.0+ is supported by. Any problem with jQuery in the above browsers should be reported as a bug in jQuery.